# Debug/Run issue with VS Code error with metals

Tags: scala, visual-studio-code, scala-metals

I have a bare bone project with just one Object

[image]

and it runs fine in sbt

[image]

I have the following in my launch.json in vs code

[image]

And when I try to run it, I get the following error:

[image]

I haven't yet been successful in finding out a solution.

Comment: What does your Metals Doctor show? (https://scalameta.org/metals/docs/editors/vscode.html#run-doctor)

Comment: Run Doctor showed no issue. The issue got resolved by moving to a new jdk. The one I was using did not support what bloop needed for debug/run